# for loop skips one round on reading values to char array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, char

So I got this weird thing that's happening to me.
I have a 2 dimensional char array, I'm suppose to put values in the array with the following conditions:

1. Each word (string) should be in a different array (different
   line)
2. "." is an indicator that it is the end of the input.

This is my code:

```
 const int MAX_STRS = 10, MAX_STR_LEN = 8;

 int main()
 {
    char dict[MAX_STRS][MAX_STR_LEN] = { 0 };

    getArray(dict);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }

 void getArray(char array[][MAX_STR_LEN])
 {
    bool dot = false;
    int i, j;
    for ( i = 0; i < MAX_STRS && !dot; i++)
      for ( j = 0; j < MAX_STR_LEN && !isspace(array[i][j - 1]); j++)
        {
         array[i][j] = cin.get();
         if (array[i][j] == '.')
          {
            dot = true;
            break;
          }
         }
  }
```

The line I'm trying to read is:

> blabla picked nice PeTer a hahaha of pickled Piper .

for some reason every time i=8, j automatically has the same value (j=8) and it skips this round of the loop.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Whenever `j` is zero you access `array[i][-1]` which can't be good.

Comment: What makes you think `j` is 8?

Comment: @AlanStokes: Possibly he used a debugger to look at it and his compiler keeps the j variable around on the stack outside the for loop scope, in which case j's value will be 8 until after the debugger steps over j's for loop.

Comment: Awsome! Didn't notice that, it worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @RoiAvram: What worked perfectly? If the fix is not one of the answers below, then write your own answer (yes that is allowed). In either case, mark one of the answers accepted (the checkbox) so people know your problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that when j=0, I asked him to check if array[-1] has whitespace.

Anyway here is the fixed code:

```
void getArray(char array[][MAX_STR_LEN])
{
bool dot = false;
int i, j;
for ( i = 0; i < MAX_STRS && !dot; i++)
    for ( j = 0; j < MAX_STR_LEN ; j++)
    {
        array[i][j] = cin.get();
        if (array[i][j] == '.')
        {
            dot = true;
            break;
        }
        if( isspace(array[i][j]))
            break;
    }
 }
```

Thank you Alan Stokes for bringing that to my attention!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is with this:
`for ( j = 0; j < MAX_STR_LEN && !isspace(array[i][j - 1]); j++)`

Ask yourself what are you reading from when j is 0? That code tries to read from `array[i][-1]`. What is that? It could be anything!

If your loop is exiting early then that `isspace` check is probably returning true.

Sometimes to debug these things you need to discard all of your assumptions and check each thing individually using a debugger or print statements.

For example you could have put this line before your for loop:
`cout << isspace(array[i][-1]);`